# Be able to use Cookie from already conected in websites in Chrome Extension

Tags: reactjs, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a Chrome extension and I wanted to know if it's possible to fetch an url of a website were i'm already connected in the browser.

I openned my web site that force me to login. When i'm logged and I type an API url (like https://mywebsite/api/whoami) in another tab on the browser, I can see the result. But when I fetch the same url in the popup extension, I get a 302 rediretion to the login. Is there a way to use the same 'cookies' reference in my popup so that I can, for any website, get the same already connected behavior ? Or do I have to do a full login logic with my own cookies ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: your extension will need its own session initialized - so yes, you will need to allow your extension to authenticate - an common way to do this would be an OAuth authorization pattern

Comment: ok thanks, I wanted to save some time but if there's no other way...

Comment: specifically the use type im assuming you are talking about is an extension like "Postman" - whereas the extension is considered its own client. If the extension is manipulating data in your already auth'd browser window, then it doesnt need to be separately auth'd (afaik)

Comment: ok, so that an extension like Postman has to manage it's own session : ok. I if understood correctly when the extension is in a webpage (content) it can fetch and will use the already auth'd data : ok. But what about code in the popup page ? Can't it acces already auth'd browser data from a webpage ? Do I have to use the background page ?